# Extract pattern substring from NSString

Tags: regex, nsstring

I've created my own UITabBarController.

Additionally I've written a few lines of code to determine the current user.

E.g. if I am the current user do/display this, otherwise do/display this etc...

The format pattern is (firstname Lastname).

The Full name of the current user is in "displayName".

This is how I set the title of the tab depending on whether I am looking at 'my' tabs or someone else's tabs.

[activities setTitle:[viewingUser objectForKey:@"displayName"]];

I now want to extract only the firstname and display it like so:

"firstname's".

I do know of substringToIndex and substringWithRange but I just can't seem to work it out myself. I reckon I just need to find the first  and extract the part it togehter with that ['s]. Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If first name and last name are separated by a space then simply execute the following statement which returns an NSArray which in your will contain the first and last names.

```
[displayName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.

I got it working like so:

[code]
NSCharacterSet *delimiter = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
NSArray *splitString = [[viewingUser objectForKey:@"displayName"] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];
NSString *xString = [splitString objectAtIndex:0]; //This contains the firstname
  //NSString *yString = [splitString objectAtIndex:1]; //This contains the lastname
[/code]


Can be called like so:

[activities setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",xString, @"'s View"]];

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation and associated sample code. There are simpler ways to do it if that is your only dataset, however, the moment you start getting into even semi-complex sequences, you'll need other, more powerful solutions. This is why I'm recommending NSScanner off the top.